# How can i check PPAPI status of Flash Plugin in Chrome using JavaScript

Tags: flash, shockwave, ppapi

Can anybody help me to get PPAPI details of Flash Plugin installed in Chrome using JavaScript ?

Here is the image containing details what i need to detect: http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-4677307-229589/450-274/plugin-detail.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Pawan

Comment: I've answered to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12866339/1491261.