# Performance issues using webcam on Google Chrome?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, webcam

We have created a webcam application in Flash, using actionscript 3.  The application runs smoothly on Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari & Opera.  However when trying it on Google Chrome the webcam experience has a severe performance drop.

We use the latest Chrome version on a Windows Vista machine.  As mentioned all other browsers runs the application just fine which makes me believe that there is some issue with the latest version of Chrome and Flash Player.

Anyone here have heard anything or knows more about the subject?  Could it be application specific reasons?  It's pretty hard to figure out what the cause could be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling Flash player and installing an older version, to see if that's the issue. Maybe do the same with Chrome too. You could also maybe upload the application somewhere and give a link (if that's OK), to see if other people have the same problem. I personally wouldn't know what's wrong, but this process of elimination might help pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: @puggsoy  I am afraid we can't upload a link for the application.  As for your suggestion I think that is the way to go, sadly.  When testing other webcam application in flash, for instance [link](http://webcamtoy.com/), on the same machine we got some drop but the applications are playable.  Which makes me think there is a code issue just specific for the Google Chrome web browser.

Comment: Okay I just tried reverting back to an 1 year old Chrome version (version 17) and the application worked great!

Then changing back to the current Chrome version (25 something) the performance drop reappears of course.

So somewhere along the line something got messed up.

I'll see if I can tweak the flash player properties rendering to see if it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable standard chrome version  flash player from

> chrome://plugins/

and enable/install own version.

Comment: Yep!  This did the trick.  Also see above comments concerning the Chrome version revert.

So yeah disabling the flash plugin as you said and then manually download the Flash Player works!

Now since Chrome natively auto upgrades flash what in the heavens are they doing that messes the Flash Player up though their automated feature?

Comment: Here is some more info.  It seems to be related to the Flash Pepper Player (FPP) that Chrome uses natively instead of the "regular" one.

[link](http://newtriks.com/2012/12/01/how-to-disable-the-chrome-pepper-flash-player/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured I would answer my own question if anyone else happen upon the same problem (which I am sure someone will!).

As explained in this thread and around the interwebs the main problem when it comes to Chrome and Flash applications is the Flash Pepper Player (FPP).  This is a player that auto updates along with Chrome to make it more user friendly.  Sadly the player is not very stable and a lot of issues can occur such as rendering problems and just plain performance issues.
This seems more prone to happen on PCs than, for instance, on Macs.

To get rid of this problem users are adviced (Not by Chrome or Adobe but by your friendly internet community) to disable the FPP (**chrome://plugins/**) and manually download the flash player as one would on IE or Firefox for instance.

Here's some more information:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866060/detecting-pepper-ppapi-flash-with-javascript)

[How to Disable the Chrome Pepper Flash Player](http://blogs.computerworld.com/desktop-apps/20845/explaining-confusion-over-flash-versions)

[Computer World](http://blogs.computerworld.com/desktop-apps/20845/explaining-confusion-over-flash-versions)

Good Luck!