# Deactivate Chrome Pepper Flash (PPAPI)

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I am quite sure that it is not possible, but I ask anyway :

I have some issues with sounds in a flash AS2 content when the PPAPI is activated.

Turning PPAPI off solve the problem.

My question is, is there any miraculous way to desactivate PPAPI from the content with javascript ?

I can detect it ([Detecting Pepper (PPAPI) Flash with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866060/detecting-pepper-ppapi-flash-with-javascript)) but users won't be able to follow the 3-steps desactivation procedure.

Thank for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054325